# How to clone trigger.newmap when passing into a trigger hanlder

Tags: apex, trigger, map, delete, clone

I was wondering how to clone trigger.newmap or how to still have access to the references associated to it when I want to pass this into a trigger handler.

Comment: What is driving the need to clone it? It's typical to pass trigger context variables directly to your handler methods. (Please [edit] to specify further)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to clone the map itself, then the following should work for most needs:

```
Map<Id, Account> = new Map<Id, Account>(Trigger.newmap);
```

... where Account is the specific type of the trigger. This will create a new map, such that if it is modified by later code, the original map of Trigger.newmap will remain unchanged.

Comment: `Trigger.newMap.clone()` works as well.